# JMeter configuration in order to upload inside Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure, jmeter, azure-blob-storage

i want to configure JMeter in order to upload files inside Azure Storage Account which i have access.
Right now, Jmeter is configured as following:

HTTP Header Manager:

```
        <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager">
          <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
            <elementProp name="" elementType="Header">
              <stringProp name="Header.name">x-ms-blob-type</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Header.value">BlockBlob</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
          </collectionProp>
        </HeaderManager>
```

HTTP Request:

```
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="HTTP request">
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">aznednatestsa01.blob.core.windows.net</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">https</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/landing?sp=racwdli&amp;st=2024-01-29T09:14:04Z&amp;se=2024-01-29T17:14:04Z&amp;sip=10.115.129.22&amp;sv=2022-11-02&amp;sr=c&amp;sig=Qyn3TQv8N5izlN8jD14hFAo66fzGiKDxe%2BWSepLUVZw%3D</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">PUT</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Files" elementType="HTTPFileArgs">
            <collectionProp name="HTTPFileArgs.files">
              <elementProp name="C:\Users\Tommaso Perilli\Downloads\performanceTestingAsset_20240122141924.parquet" elementType="HTTPFileArg">
                <stringProp name="File.mimetype">application/octent-stream</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="File.path">C:\Users\Tommaso Perilli\Downloads\performanceTestingAsset_20240122141924.parquet</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="File.paramname">performanceTestingAsset_20240122141924.parquet</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.postBodyRaw">false</boolProp>
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
```

After launch JMeter, the error raised is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:02f855a0-401e-0042-3e96-528366000000
Time:2024-01-29T09:33:42.8148368Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was racwdli
2024-01-29T09:14:04Z
2024-01-29T17:14:04Z
/blob/aznednatestsa01/$root

10.115.129.22

2022-11-02
c
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks

I try to upload files inside Azure Storage Account by JMeter

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you don't supply sufficient amount of headers.

Your request fails due to missing proper [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header so take a look at [Authorize requests to Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage), identify the authorization method you want to proceed with and amend your [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) configuration accordingly.

Then get familiarized with [Put Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob?tabs=microsoft-entra-id) API endpoint documentation and provide other headers which are `Required`

[image]

Comment: About authorization header, is it correct to add Authorization key and value "SharedAccessSignature sp=racwdli&st=2024-01-29T11:10:43Z&se=2024-01-29T19:10:43Z&sip=81.56.17.92&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=%2FJS8VDdjbLBqOB%2Fm8H6qH06njktNuAmTxt1j5XcAduI%3D" in HTTP Header Manager?

Comment: i changed HTTP Header Manager, this is the result i got: 
<stringProp name="Header.name">x-ms-blob-type
<stringProp name="Header.value">BlockBlob
<stringProp name="Header.name">Authorization
<stringProp name="Header.value">SharedAccessSignature ...
<stringProp name="Header.name">x-ms-date
<stringProp ">Sun, 29 Jan 2024 11:10:43 GMT
<stringProp >x-ms-version
<stringProp >2023-07-20
<stringProp >comp
<stringProp >list
<stringProp >restype
<stringProp >container
<stringProp ">Content-Length
<stringProp >0
<stringProp ">Content-Type
<stringProp >application/octet-stream

Comment: I don't think your header value is correct, check out [Example: Get a Blob using a Container’s Shared Access Signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/storageservices/service-sas-examples#example-get-a-blob-using-a-containers-shared-access-signature) article which shows how you can generate the signature. The code example can be put in [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and you will need to convert it into [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Sorry the signature is correct, it's generated by Portal Azure platform directly by target Storage Account